# Will a black painted bottom of a heated swimming pool reduce the amount of electricity needed significantly?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation

I was watching a programme on tv. A woman showed her swimming pool. You could see a circular black pool. She said it was painted black "to make it more energy neutral". This is obviously true.
But, how much will painting the pool black reduce the amount of energy needed to heat it? Say in summer, when the average temperature is 20 degrees and you want to heat the pool to 27 degrees.

I tried to look it up on the net. Of course, the construction companies say it does. And it does. But I couldn't find the actual computation how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on too many factors to give a precise result.

- How much insolation is the pool receiving?  Insolation is the number of watts per square meter received by the surface area of the pool.  This will vary depending on the time of day, weather conditions, and the elevation of the sun in the sky (which itself depends on the pool's latitude and the time of year.)  This can be looked up for many situations;  you're looking for the "horizontal insolation" at a given location and time of day.
- What fraction of the sunlight is being reflected from the water surface?  This depends on the elevation of the sun as well.  It can be calculated from the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) using the index of refraction of water, about $n_2 = 1.33$.  For most solar elevations this will be less than 5%, but if the sun is low in the sky a substantial fraction of the sunlight will be reflected and will never reach the bottom of the pool.
- How much does the albedo of the pool bottom decrease?  Albedo is the fraction of the sunlight that is reflected from a surface.  For black, it should be pretty close to 0;  for a white pool bottom, it will be in the range of 0.5–0.9 depending on the paint used;  for a blue pool bottom, it will be somewhere in between these numbers.
- What fraction of the energy imparted to the pool bottom goes into the ground, and what fraction goes into the water?  This will depend on the soil conditions and how the pool base was constructed, as well as how quickly the water is circulating in the pool.

All of these would be necessary to figure out how much thermal power is being imparted to the water.  In addition, if you want to translate this into a target temperature, you would need to know:

- How quickly does the pool water lose its heat to the surrounding environment?    This will depend on the temperature of the surrounding air, the temperature of the water, the amount of evaporation that occurs to the surrounding air, and how efficiently the water can lose its energy to the environment.  These would depend, in turn, on the ambient air temperature, the ambient humidity, and how quickly the water in the pool is circulating.  (Presumably a black bottom will lead to pretty strong convection, which would differ from a white bottom.)

Comment: I guess checking the electricity meter before painting it black and after will indeed be easier!